# End-to-end Schengen and D-type visas; what is the worst that could happen if I don't re-enter the country?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, overstaying, student-visas

I have a Schengen visa which ends on the 15th and my D-type visa starts on the 16th, for Germany. Given the current situation of the pandemic, I don't want to go to my home country and come back.

I've asked various officials whether I need to go out of the country and come back; border police said I need to, foreign office (where I'm applying for a residence permit) said I don't need to, so I'm a bit confused.

What could worse happen if I don't exit and re-enter the country and later they say I needed to?

Comment: One thing that could easily happen is the “Foreigner's office” refusing to entertain your application for a residence permit, forcing you to leave the country and restart the visa application process from scratch elsewhere. That's why their opinion is more important than that of the police.

Comment: You don't have to go as far as your home country.  You could go to Croatia, Romania, the UK, Kaliningrad, etc., and then turn around immediately and reenter the Schengen area.

Comment: @phoog how can I enter to those countries without a visa?

Comment: Whether you can enter most of those countries without a visa depends on your nationality, which you have not disclosed.  But you can enter Schengen candidate states with a Schengen visa in most cases (for example Croatia, Bulgaria, Romania).

Comment: @phoog Schengen Annex countries require you to possess a valid multiple entry visa or residence permit to gain entry. OP most likely would get denied as he is attempting to enter these countries in the gap betwen validity of the two visas.
OP could still do this if his nationality allows a visa free entrance to any of these countries.

Comment: @MaxPayne but there is no gap.  And depending on his or her nationality there may be some other nearby country that could serve the purpose.  But in the end it seems that it's not necessary, as shown in the answer.

Comment: I crossed from Schengen into Romania in February on the last evening of my Schengen stay with no problem at all. But I was under a visa waiver or visa-free entry in both.

Comment: I also added a reopen vote to this question. It is about the transition between a short, touristic stay and a longer stay, so I think we should be fair enough to accept this as being withing the scope of this forum.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo yeah I agree. Plus, if it is off-topic why don't they just it to expats.SE, instead of closing it; I just can't understand the logic.

Answer (score 8):

Since D-Visas, that are issued to take up a residence, are **authorized by the Foreigners Authority** (Ausländerbehörde), *they will know best* what type of visa they have issued and how it can be used.

The **Schengen Borders Code** does require that somebody leaves and reenter the Schengen Area so that the compliance with the 90/180 days rule can be checked.

A **National D-Visa** can be issued to **override** this rule

- AVwV AufenthG, Ziff. **6.1.8.2** (after a National Visa ends)
- AVwV AufenthG, Ziff. **6.1.8.3** (before a National Visa starts)

You should check your D-Visa *Remarks* field to see if it (also) contains:

- **§ 7 Absatz 1 Satz 3 AufenthG**

If yes, then it is a clear cut case. The fact that the D-Visa starts the day after the C-Visa expires is also a sign that it was issued with this situation in mind.

---

> [Page 138/139 of Visahandbook](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/blob/207816/e70e66c715d4dafd0f1bd7f8585b0e53/visumhandbuch-data.pdf)
> **Berechnung der Bezugszeiträume bei Schengen-Visa/ Anrechnung von Voraufenthaltszeiten**
> ...
> (b) Rechtmäßiger Aufenthalt in Deutschland
> Sowohl bei „Negativstaatern“ (Staatsangehörige der Drittländer, die in Anhang I der Verordnung (EG) Nummer 539/2001 des Rates zur Aufstellung der Liste der Drittländer, deren Staatsangehörige beim Überschreiten der Außengrenzen im Besitz eines Visums sein müssen) als auch bei „Positivstaatern“ (Staatsangehörigen der Drittländer, die in Anhang II der o. a. Verordnung aufgeführt sind) ist es grundsätzlich bei einem kurzfristigen Aufenthalt, der an einen Aufenthalt in Deutschland nach nationalem Recht anschließt (z.B. als Student), notwendig, dass erst eine Ausreise aus dem Schengen-Gebiet und eine anschließende Wiedereinreise erfolgt, damit die **erforderlichen Einreisevoraussetzungen nach Art. 6 Abs. 1 Schengener Grenzkodex überprüft werden können**.
>
> > **Calculation of reference periods for Schengen visas / crediting of periods of previous residence**
> > ...
> > (b) Legal residence in Germany
> > Both in the case of "negative states" (nationals of third countries listed in Annex I of Regulation (EC) No. 539/2001 of the Council establishing the list of third countries whose nationals are in possession of a visa when crossing the external borders  must) as well as in the case of "positive states" (nationals of third countries listed in Appendix II of the above regulation), it is generally necessary for a short-term stay that follows a stay in Germany according to national law (e.g. as a student) that  an exit from the Schengen area and a subsequent re-entry take place **so that the necessary entry requirements according to Art. 6 Para. 1 of the Schengen Borders Code can be checked**.
>
> **Eine Ausnahme** bildet die Erteilung einer für drei Monate gültigen Aufenthaltserlaubnis durch die Ausländerbehörde nach § 7 Absatz 1 Satz 3 AufenthG bei Vorliegen bestimmter Voraussetzungen. **Hintergrund ist, dass man Ausländern den Aufwand einer aus rein formalen Gründen vorzunehmenden Aus- und Wiedereinreise ersparen möchte**.
>
> Zur weiteren Erläuterung siehe : AVwV AufenthG, Ziff. 6.1.8.2 und **6.1.8.3**
>
> > **An exception** is the issuance of a residence permit valid for three months by the immigration authorities in accordance with Section 7 (1) sentence 3 of the Residence Act if certain requirements are met.  **The background to this is that one would like to save foreigners the effort of leaving and re-entering the country for purely formal reasons**.
> >
> > For further explanation see: AVwV AufenthG, no.  6.1.8.2 and **6.1.8.3**

---

**Sources**:

- [Visumhandbuch - Zusammenstellung der Erlasslage im Auswärtigen Amt zur Visumvergabe mit den wesentlichen Weisungen und Erläuterungen zur Anwendung der Vorschriften des nationalen und europäischen Visumrechts durch die deutschen Auslandvertretungen](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/blob/207816/e70e66c715d4dafd0f1bd7f8585b0e53/visumhandbuch-data.pdf) (PDF)

  - June 2019, issue 69

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111637/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-johnson-end-to-end-schengen-and-d-type-visa-what-c).

Comment: This answer is seen as wrong by some people, see the chatroom for details.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is incorrect.  It says

> The Schengen Borders Code does require that somebody leaves and reenter the Schengen Area so that the compliance with the 90/180 days rule can be checked.

In fact, the Schengen Borders Code says nothing of the kind.  It says that passport stamps must be checked when people enter and exit the Schengen area, and it says that those entering for a short stay must have their stamps checked for compliance with the 90/180 rule.   It does not directly address the question of switching between a short stay and a D visa.

Comment: AFAIK the border code also says that time spend on a long term visa does not count towards the days taken in to consideration for the 90/180 rule. So when leaving the entry and exit stamps will be compared, the number of days on the D visa will be subtracted, and if you are then shown in compliance with the 90/180 rules there is no issue.

Comment: @KristvanBesien You are right. Entry and exit stamps are not required to correctly count the days in connection with a national long term visa. This was thoroughly discussed yesterday in comments to Mark's answer, but Willeke moved the comment thread to chat, which noone bothers to read, so the accepted answer now stands without any obvious objections no matter how wrong it is. I am also unsure how to deal with such situations and was wondering if it is worth a discussion on meta?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo "the accepted answer now stands without any obvious objections" is precisely why I posted this answer.  There are plenty of examples of questions on [so] where the accepted answer is misleading or incorrect, but the asker of the question is not a regular user so hasn't returned to accept the better answer below.

Comment: The accepted answer is locked, but may still be downvoted.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Can somebody explain to me how 90/180 rule isn't relevant to the question that is being asked?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica anything?

Comment: @onurcanbektas The very purpose of a long-stay visa (type D) is to allow stays longer than 90 days. After August 16th, you cannot be fined or otherwise sanctioned for staying longer than 90 days as you have a document explicitly issued for this purpose. That's why the Borders Code explicitly excludes periods covered by a long-stay visa from the count and the stamps become completely useless. What would they prove?

Comment: @Relaxed but my short-term visa expires on the 15th!

Comment: @onurcanbektas Yes and until the 15th, if the police want to assess your status, they would check for your last entry stamp and want to see one that is less than 90 days old (taking earlier stays into account). What's important is what happens after that. What do the stamps prove? That you stayed until the 15th? That can be assumed and treated accordingly even if you had no exit stamp. That you stayed beyond the 15th? Same thing without stamps and that would not have any consequences as far as the Schengen Borders Code is concerned because you have a D-visa.

Comment: Forget the stamps for a minute: How do yo think the 90/180 rule is relevant to your situation? Are you planning to stay out of Germany for 90 days? If not, you don't need to prove that you did and the stamps are irrelevant. Ultimately the stamps are a means to an end (enforcing short-stay rules), nothing more. That's the bit Mark seems to have misinterpreted and the reason why you should accept phoog's answer rather than Mark's.

Comment: @phoog I realize that, but your answer is also not really answering the question, just pointing out that the other answer is wrong and therefore perhaps just an abuse of the answer functionality to comment on the other answer, which is now not allowed? :-) Had I known the correct answer to the question, I would sure have written one myself, but I don't. It is just obvious that everything Mark states in his answer is either wrong or not at all related to the question.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Even without leaving and reentering, it is based on the stamps you already have, possible to determine that you must have stayed within the Schengen area at the day of transition from a short term to a long term stay or vice versa. Changing status from a short to a long term (national visa) stay, the 90/180 clock stops the day before the national visa starts, as if you had left the Schengen area. The other way around, the clock starts again the first day following the validity of the long term visa as if you had entered.

Comment: @onurcanbektas No further stamps are required in these situations to do the 90/180 calculation correctly and nothing else is claimed in the German handbooks and administrative regulations, no matter how much Mark is trying to convince you otherwise.

Comment: @Relaxed I wouldn't be over-hasty about accepting this answer.  It doesn't entirely answer the question as asked; it's more of a rebuttal to a single point in the accepted answer.  If nobody writes a more thorough answer, I may consider expanding this one, but I don't have time to do so today.

Comment: @phoog Do you have any resources from German authorities on how they see the situation? The visa handbook and the administrative regulations should have been the right place to look, but they only describe the situation of a short-term stay (with or without visa) directly following a long term stay and a visa-free stay preceding a long-term stay. I can't find anything about this situation, when someone is staying on a short-term visa preceding a long-term visa.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I don't have such a resource and I don't have much time these days to look for anything.

Comment: @phoog I would really appreciate fi you could expand your answer.

Comment: I've retracted the acceptance of the other answer.